# Jekyll - Loop .SVG includes

Tags: html, for-loop, svg, jekyll

I have a directory in my Jekyll Project called **Icons**.

I would very much like Jekyll to display any .svg files within that directory within a list.

At the moment, I've constructed a for loop like this:

```
<ul>
{% for icon in site.icons %}
<li>
  <p class="icon">{{ icon.content }}</p>
  <span>{{ icon.name }}</span>  
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My .svg files look like this:

```
---
Name: Camera
---
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="9 36.345 125.943 98.655" enable-background="new 9 36.345 125.943 98.655"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M58.332,43.339c0-3.869-3.186-6.994-7.041-6.994H31.884c-3.857,0-6.92,3.125-6.92,6.994v4h33.368V43.339z M92.157,72.39
            c-12.197,0.024-22.091,9.909-22.109,22.148c0.018,12.229,9.912,22.14,22.109,22.155c12.208-0.017,22.098-9.926,22.116-22.155
            C114.255,82.299,104.365,72.414,92.157,72.39z M128.391,53.29H15.557C11.938,53.29,9,56.218,9,59.864l0.002,68.565
            c0,3.637,2.936,6.57,6.555,6.57h112.833c3.627,0,6.553-2.936,6.553-6.57V59.864C134.943,56.218,132.005,53.29,128.391,53.29z
             M51.047,73.904c0,2.168-1.761,3.945-3.929,3.945H25.92c-2.173,0-3.937-1.777-3.937-3.945l-0.031-4.588
            c0.244-1.932,1.88-3.44,3.884-3.44h21.387c2.005,0,3.633,1.509,3.879,3.44L51.047,73.904z M92.159,125.464
            c-17.058,0-30.87-13.841-30.87-30.924c0-17.084,13.812-30.943,30.87-30.943c17.062,0,30.89,13.859,30.896,30.943
            C123.049,111.623,109.221,125.464,92.159,125.464z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

At the moment, nothing is being generated in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a [collection](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).

In **_config.yml** add a collection :

```
collections:
 - icons
```

Create an ***icons*** folder in root folder. Note the  undescore.

Put your SVGs inside **_icons** folder.

And your good to go.

Comment: How can I place each item in that collection into a <li> ?

Comment: Just use the loop you use in you question, it will work.